# How to sort version numbers

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and have one field called "versions". The general sorting of table in descending order is displayed below:

```
2.3
2.2
2.12
2.11
2.1
```

But I need the sorting in descending order as shown below:

```
2.12
2.11
2.3
2.2
2.1
```

My JavaScript code:

```
function TestTable1(searchLabel) {

    $('#datatable-1').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [
            [0, "asc"]
        ],
            "sDom": "<'box-content'<'col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 text-right'l><'clearfix'>>rt<'box-content'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6 text-right'p><'clearfix'>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search in " + searchLabel + ":<br>",
                "sLengthMenu": '_MENU_'
        }
    });
}
```

What is the logic I need to change here?

Comment: If you can think of a logical way of describing a sorting algorithm for your use case then it should be easy enough to code it. What is the logic behind your sorting? Also, it looks like you want to alter the ordering rather than the searching of the DataTable, is that correct?

Comment: Do you want to sort on the digits after the decimal point - 12,11,3,2,1? Do you also want to search on the integer part, ie the integer part THEN the decimal part?

Comment: Yes, integer part followed by the decimal part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You need to use custom sorting function to order version numbers correctly, see the code below.

If needed, change `0` in `"aTargets": [0]` to the appropriate zero-based index of the version column.

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "version-pre": function ( d ) {
       var a = d.split("."), res = "";
       for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          res += ("0000000000" + a[i]).slice(-10);
       }   
       return res;
    },   
    "version-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "version-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }    
});

function TestTable1(searchLabel) {    
    $('#datatable-1').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
        "sDom": "<'box-content'<'col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 text-right'l><'clearfix'>>rt<'box-content'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6 text-right'p><'clearfix'>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search in " + searchLabel + ":<br>",
            "sLengthMenu": '_MENU_'
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
           { "aTargets": [0], "sType": 'version' }
        ]
    });
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euvoLxx9/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you :)